# possible web protocols in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, network-protocols

What are the alternatives to HTTP (per [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/)) when establishing a server connection in JavaScript? The only one I know is the [WebSocket protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) (per [`WebSocket`](http://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/)). Their corresponding secure variants https and wss included.

Would it be possible to choose an arbitrary protocol with JavaScript? How do you communicate with NTP, IMAP, UDP etc. -services for example in Node.js?

Comment: Protocols accessibility is based on technology you use, not the language. That why possibilities with node.js is different to possibilities in browsers using javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Node.js, you can do pretty much anything. E.g. UDP is directly supported ([dgram](http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html) module which is shipped with node.js), and npm has a plethora of third-party modules for many other protocols, such as SMTP, IMAP, FTP and XMPP; see https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules for one list. And if you can't find a ready made module for your favorite protocol, you can implement one yourself.

Now when it comes to browsers, you are much more limited. Those you listed are all I know (browser plugins excluded, of course). So you'd need to connect to a proxy server with HTTP(S) or ws(s) and do the actual protocol stuff from there.

Comment: What about TCP? How come node.js support `UDP` and not `TCP`?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka [It does](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html), just used UDP as an example.

Comment: I thought node.js is a server side framework - running javascript on the server side. So this can be used in a browser?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka, AFAIK not, since running NodeJS with modules is something different than running JavaScript in a browser (on a client PC).